# How deep should PVC drain pipe be buried to ensure grass will grow above ground?

Tags: drainage, pvc, lawn, grass

I’m burying 4” solid PVC drain pipe (not a French drain) in my yard for downspout & surface drainage. How deep should the pipes be buried in order to ensure that grass will grow above it?

Due to a limited amount of drainage fall on my property, in a certain section I may need to bury the pipe close to the surface (1-2”), and I fear that will mean I’ll end up with a strip of brown grass right where the pipe is.

Comment: As long as dirt is surrounding the pipe, the grass roots will grow around the pipe.

Comment: you can raise the grass around the pipe if needed by slowly adding sand+soil, about 1/4" a month.

Answer (score 1):

One to two inches of soil above the pipe should be plenty. I often get significant stands of grass growing in the soil that accumulates along the edges of my sidewalk if I don't keep up with edging it. And that's often a half inch or less.

And as Gunner says in the comments, with a 4" diameter pipe, the grass roots will have no problem working their way around the pipe to find deeper soil to put down some good roots.